# Using regex to extract hyperlink text from Python string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the display text for each hyperlink in a giant string. (The string is obtained by opening and reading an .rtf file, and the file has many hyperlinks.) The hyperlinks are generally in the format `{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.mywebsite.com/"}{\fldrslt Click Here}}` (I want Click Here), but often contain a lot of nested formatting with newlines:

Example 1 (I want to extract Leonard T. Strand): `text I don't want {\\field {\\*\\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.westlaw.com/Link/Document/FullText?findType=h&pubNum=176284&cite=0226771601&originatingDoc=I2e197170e0a011eaa13ca2bed92d37fc&refType=RQ&originationContext=document&vr=3.0&rs=cblt1.0&transitionType=DocumentItem&contextData=(sc.Search)" }{\\fldrslt \n{\\b0 \\cf5 \\f2 \\ul0 \\strike0 \\i0 \\fs20 \\sa0 \\sb0 \nLeonard T. Strand\n}}} text I don't want`

Example 2 (I want to extract Morgan v. Robinson and 920 F.3d 521, 523 (8th Cir. 2019): `text I don't want {\\field {\\*\\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.westlaw.com/Link/Document/FullText?findType=Y&serNum=2047938005&pubNum=0000506&originatingDoc=I2e197170e0a011eaa13ca2bed92d37fc&refType=RP&fi=co_pp_sp_506_523&originationContext=document&vr=3.0&rs=cblt1.0&transitionType=DocumentItem&contextData=(sc.Search)#co_pp_sp_506_523" }{\\fldrslt \n{\\b0 \\cf5 \\f2 \\i1 \\fs20 \n{\\b0 \\cf5 \\f2 \\ul0 \\strike0 \\i1 \\fs20 \\sa0 \\sb0 \nMorgan v. Robinson\n}\n}\n{\\b0 \\cf5 \\f2 \\ul0 \\strike0 \\i0 \\fs20 \\sa0 \\sb0 \n, 920 F.3d 521, 523 (8th Cir. 2019)\n}}} text I don't want`

This works for the first type but not for the second: `regex = re.compile('\n?\}?\n\{\\\\field.*\\\\fldrslt \n.*\n(.*)\n')` Ideally, I'd like something more generalizeable that fits the broad structure of the hyperlink, but the multiple text locations in example 2 are giving me problems.

Comment: Why don’t you match ‘HYPERLINK\s+“(http.*?)”’ and then use group 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example data, you might use a specific match for the `field` and `fldinst` part. Then after `fldinst` match the rest of the line, followed by all the lines that do start with `{`

Then capture the all following lines in group 1 until you encounter `}}}`

Then from capture group 1, remove all lines that start with either `{` or `}` or a comma.

**Note** that this is based on the example data, and does not take balanced curly brackets into account.

Pattern to get group 1

```
{\\\\field\s*{\\\\\*\\\\fldinst HYPERLINK\s+"https?://[^"]+"\s+}{\\\\fldrslt.*\r?\n((?:(?!}}}).*\r?\n)*)}}}
```

About the pattern

- `{\\\\field\s*{\\\\\*\\\\fldinst HYPERLINK\s+"https?://[^"]+"\s+}` Match the *field* and the HYPERLINK part
- `{\\\\fldrslt.*\r?\n` Match the *fldrslt* part
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:(?!}}}).*\r?\n)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with `}}}`
- `)` Close group 1
- `}}}` Match ending `}}}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2Usc1/1)

Pattern to remove all unwanted lines from group 1

```
^(?:[{}].*[\r\n]*|,[^\S\r\n]*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[{}].*[\r\n]*` Match a line start starts with `{` or `}`
  - `|` Or
  - `,[^\S\r\n]*` Match a `,` followed by optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rbhn00/1)

Example code

```
import re
 
regex = r"{\\\\field\s*{\\\\\*\\\\fldinst HYPERLINK\s+\"https?://[^\"]+\"\s+}{\\\\fldrslt.*\r?\n((?:(?!}}}).*\r?\n)*)}}}"
 
test_str = ("text I don't want {\\\\field {\\\\*\\\\fldinst HYPERLINK \"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...w.com/Link/Document/FullText?findType=Y&serNum=2047938005&pubNum=0000506&originatingDoc=I2e197170e0a011eaa13ca2bed92d37fc&refType=RP&fi=co_pp_sp_506_523&originationContext=document&vr=3.0&rs=cblt1.0&transitionType=DocumentItem&contextData=(sc.Search)#co_pp_sp_506_523\" }{\\\\fldrslt \n"
            "{\\\\b0 \\\\cf5 \\\\f2 \\\\i1 \\\\fs20 \n"
            "{\\\\b0 \\\\cf5 \\\\f2 \\\\ul0 \\\\strike0 \\\\i1 \\\\fs20 \\\\sa0 \\\\sb0 \n"
            "Morgan v. Robinson\n"
            "}\n"
            "}\n"
            "{\\\\b0 \\\\cf5 \\\\f2 \\\\ul0 \\\\strike0 \\\\i0 \\\\fs20 \\\\sa0 \\\\sb0 \n"
            ", 920 F.3d 521, 523 (8th Cir. 2019)\n"
            "}}} text I don't want\n\n"
            "text I don't want {\\\\field {\\\\*\\\\fldinst HYPERLINK \"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...w.com/Link/Document/FullText?findType=h&pubNum=176284&cite=0226771601&originatingDoc=I2e197170e0a011eaa13ca2bed92d37fc&refType=RQ&originationContext=document&vr=3.0&rs=cblt1.0&transitionType=DocumentItem&contextData=(sc.Search)\" }{\\\\fldrslt \n"
            "{\\\\b0 \\\\cf5 \\\\f2 \\\\ul0 \\\\strike0 \\\\i0 \\\\fs20 \\\\sa0 \\\\sb0 \n"
            "Leonard T. Strand\n"
            "}}} text I don't want")
 
for g in re.findall(regex, test_str):
    print(re.sub(r"^(?:[{}].*[\r\n]*|,[^\S\r\n]*)", "", g, 0, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
Morgan v. Robinson
920 F.3d 521, 523 (8th Cir. 2019)

Leonard T. Strand
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/9YVyFo)